# How to process http request inside an object literal?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, xmlhttprequest, object-literal

I'm currently learning about design patterns and am refactoring some code to follow the object literal pattern. However, I'm not sure how to process an http request while using this pattern.

Usually I would process the data within the request itself. But is there a way to do the following?

```
let myObj = {

  makeRequest: function () {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'url')
    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // somehow this.response gets stored into myObj.returnedData
        myObj.processRequest(this.response) // this works
      }
    }
    request.send()
  },

  processRequest: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }

  init: function () {
    this.makeRequest()
  }
}

myObj.init()
```

I suspect that maybe I'm going about this all wrong, any pointers appreciated.

references to object literal pattern:

- http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code
- https://youtu.be/m-NYyst_tiY?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f&t=584

Comment: “The object literal pattern” isn’t a thing. Consider taking your usual code to [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: `returnedData: void 0`, `myObj.returnedData = this.response; if (myObj.returnedData !== undefined) myObj.anotherFunc()`

Comment: You should try it yourself and report the problems in your question. anotherFunc should be called on the "// somehow ... " line.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, I've added references and thank you I'll keep code review in mind.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks I was getting too caught up with incorrect `this` references and bind and didn't realise I could just reference the object itself. I don't understand `void 0` but looking into it

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks I was trying to call functions and return values at this line - but was overcomplicating things. Have updated code with something that is working for my purposes